# setPropertyメソッドを使用してもcontentプロパティへ値が反映されない

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

```
:root{
    --name: "＊";
}

.test::before{
    font-size: 13px;
    Content: var(--name);
}
```

このcss変数をjsから

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--name", "test");
```

というふうに操作したいのですが、これを実行しても ＊ が消えるだけで test という文字が反映されません。
これの原因を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()` において `setProperty("--name", "test")` を呼び出したとき、プロパティに設定する値 **`test` は文字列ではなく、 `test` という値**となります。このため、 `content` プロパティでは不正な値が設定されたことで、エラーが発生します。以上が「`＊` が消えるだけで test という文字列が反映されない」原因です。

この問題を解決するには、 `setProperty` メソッドへ値を渡すときに、値が文字列だと明確にしなければなりません。このためには、異なる文字列リテラルや `JSON.stringify` メソッドが使用出来ます。

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--name", `"test"`);
// または `'test'` や "'test'" など
```

```css
:root{
    --name: "＊";
}

.test::before{
    font-size: 13px;
    content: var(--name);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--name", JSON.stringify("test"));
```

```css
:root{
    --name: "＊";
}

.test::before{
    font-size: 13px;
    content: var(--name);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```